# Can't run script from another script

Tags: python, abaqus

I'd like to end a process after certain conditions are met within a script.
like this:

```
import psutil
PROCNAME = "standard.exe"

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            proc.kill()
```

I can run this standalone script (processkiller.py) in Spyder and it works but I'd would like
to run this script from another script, like this:

```
os.system("C:\\Users\\s086372\\Desktop\\results\ProcessKiller.py")
```

This doesn't work, any suggestions? I'm still a beginner who is using 
simple codes to script engineering simulations.

the `mdb.jobs.kill(`) within abaqus doesn't work, it's bugging, so I have to manually kill the process in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
os.system("python C:\\Users\\s086372\\Desktop\\results\ProcessKiller.py")
```

You have to pass the .py to the python interpreter.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I can run my script from Spyder and it will end the process but not from my mainscript: 

os.system("python C:\\Users\\s086372\\Desktop\results\ProcessKiller.py")
print 'Process has been killed'


I do get the print message afterwards, but no errors

Comment: Maybe you don't have the rights to kill the process, try:

os.system("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator python C:\\Users\\s086372\\Desktop\\results\ProcessKiller.py")

Comment: Try adding : "proc.terminate()" juste before "proc.kill()"

Comment: I will try this, it really bugs me that the script works independently but somehow it doesn't if I call it from my main script. I have to add that my mainscript doesnt run the processkiller.py at all. I added a print message to the proceskiller.py which doesnt show up

Comment: Ok this didn't work either, now I managed to import the psutil module into the abaqus scripting environment, so I have just one script. 

PROCNAME = "standard.exe"
  
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
   print ('Entered the For loop ')
   if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
    print ('Entered the if statement ')
    proc.terminate()
    proc.kill()

I do enter the for loop since I get the print message, but the script doesn't pass the 'IF' statement